# Foundation 6 Sites - Dropdown Close On Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 6.2 to design my registration page. Everything is working fine.But now I want to open dropdown pane on focus on input field and close on focusout. I searched in google but there is no solution I found. Please help me to solve this. Thank You.

Here is my code for dropdown:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
          <label>
            <input id="newPass" type="password" placeholder="New Password" name="newPass" data-toggle="pass-tips" onkeyup="checkPassword(); return false;">
            <span id="chk-newPass" class="form-error"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-pane left" id="pass-tips" data-dropdown data-close-on-click="true" >
            <div class="row">
              <div class="medium-12 columns">
                <h6>Tips for strong password: </h6>
                <ul class="no-bullet">
                  <li><i id="pass-tips-char" class="fa fa-check-circle check-circle-green" aria-hidden="true"></i> Use at least 8 characters.</li>
                  <li><i id="pass-tips-upper"  class="fa fa-check-circle check-circle-green" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contain at least an uppercase letter.</li>
                  <li><i id="pass-tips-special" class="fa fa-check-circle check-circle-green" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contain at least a special character.</li>
                  <li><i id="pass-tips-num" class="fa fa-check-circle check-circle-green" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contain at least a number.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
          <label>
            <input id="confirmPass" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPass">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<script>
$('#newPass').on("focus", function(){
    $("#pass-tips").foundation('open');
});

$("#newPass").focusout(function(){
    $("#pass-tips").foundation('close');
});
</script>
```